# ¿Porque el scroll no sube?

Tags: html, scroll

Tengo un problema con el scroll de mi pagina.Cuando estoy a mitad de pagina o simplemente bajarlo un poco y trato de actualizar mi pagina,ya sea con F5 o clicando el botón actualizar del navegador,la pagina se queda ahí mismo;no hace nada.O sea, no vuelve arriba.

Comment: ¿Podrías enseñarnos tu código o recrear un ejemplo en el que podamos ver el efecto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eso tienes que usar un poco de `javascript`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Tu codigo funciona,pero porque cuando actualizo la pagina algunos elementos tiemblan(no se si sea la palabra correcta).Es normal?

Comment: @luis - ni idea... borra el cache y mira ver si cambia slgo

Comment: Pero no importa.Lo dejare asi,creo que es normal.Probe con otras paginas.Gracias!!.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es el cache de tu navegador.

De manera manual se puede actualizar la página del navegador Mozilla Firefox con 'Ctrl + F5'.